# Mongodb findandmodify authorization

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB user created into `admin` database

When i try to use some functions in the database it throws an error:

> { name: 'MongoError',
>     message: 'not authorized on stop to execute command { findandmodify: "users", query: { _id: 1 }, new: true, remove: false, upsert: true, update: {...

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "xxxx",
            "storedKey" : "xxxx",
            "serverKey" : "xxxx"
        }
    },
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any other commands like `find` or `update` works.

I want this user to be a `SUPER USER` but I have assigned it all type of roles, but none of them works, i tried `root`, `adminAnyDatabase`, etc.

I'm using mongodb 3.0.9

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Database permissions should be discussed on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). But obviously there is no "write" permission granted. `adminAnyDatabase` is not a blanket role for being able to write on a database or collection.

Comment: Sorry, i will ask there. Thank you.